# Moving dimension text in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, dimensions

I am labeling a 2-D area with several intersecting dimension labels, and I would like to move the dimension text ('512.64 ft') over to the sides of the polygon to make it easier to interpret.

However, I can't find a way to move these labels, nor can I convert the labels to annotations like I would with a normal feature class.

Using ArcMap 10.3.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, be sure you have the Labeling toolbar enabled and that you have checked the Use Maplex Label Engine option.

Select Label Manager option (should be the first icon on the left). Choose Properties > Label Position > choose the position you want. There should be a May shift label upon fixed position box that you can check.

Answer (score 0):

For more control over "dimension" lines and text than the automated dimensioning you may want to consider using a line feature class to draw them instead:

- you can symbolize such "dimension" lines using an arrow head at each end
- you can place the "dimension" text into a field and use it for labelling.  These labels can be converted to annotation for even finer control.

Comment: Thanks for you help, this is actually exactly what I ended up doing, even before I read this!